# cv2.resize() error: saves the same picture with different names

Tags: python, opencv

I am new in programming and trying to make an image resizer. I wanted to make possibility to write custom prefix by the user before in the filenames. Sizes are also customable.

The cv2.imshow() works fine, but cv2.resize() does not. If I check it with imshow, it shows only one picture despite of the for loop, and then cv2.imwrite saves only one picture with the names all the selected pictures.
The lists seems to be OK.

I hope I am clear, the code:

```
def openfiles():

    global picture_original
    global file_path
    global f

    # Valid filetypes
    file_types=[("Jpeg files","*.jpg"),("PNG files","*.png"),("BMP files","*.bmp"),("all files","*.*")]

    window.filenames =  filedialog.askopenfilenames(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (file_types)) # TUPLE of filepath/filenames

    #f = []

    # Creating a list from the tuple
    for pics in window.filenames:
        f.append(pics)

        f = [picture.replace('/', "\\") for picture in f]

    try:
        for picture in f:
            picture_original = cv2.imread(picture, 1)
            #cv2.imshow("Preview", picture_original)
            #cv2.waitKey(1)
    except:
        msgbox_openerror() # Error opening the file

    # Getting the filepath only from the list "f":
    file_path = f[0].rsplit("\\",1)[0]
    view_list()

def save_command():
    """
    function to save the resized pictures
    """
    global picture_resized
    global prefix
    prefix = "Resized_"
    lst_filename = []
    lst_renamed = []

    for i in f:
        #print(f)
        path,filename = os.path.split(i) # path - only filepath | filename - only filename with extension
        lst_filename.append(prefix+filename)

    for i in range(len(f)):
        lst_renamed.append(os.path.join(path, lst_filename[i]))

    for i in range(len(f)):
        picture_resized = cv2.resize(picture_original, ((int(width.get())), int(height.get())))
        cv2.imshow("Preview", picture_resized)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

    for i in lst_renamed:
        cv2.imwrite(i, picture_resized)
```

I hope someone have some ideas. Thank you in advance!

Comment: What do you expect `picture_original` to contain after `openfiles()` finished?

Comment: Or `picture_resized`... there's nothing in the loop that does the resizing that would depends on the value of `i` -- so you're basically repeating the same thing on the same inputs over and over again. Similarly, in the loop with `imwrite`, the only thing that changes is the file name. | If you have more than one filename to process (and as such store them in a list), you should also have more than one image (and store them in a list).

Comment: I expect 'picture_original' and 'picture_resized' should be a list of numpy arrays. Their type should be  <class "numpy.ndarray'>
Yes, you may be right related to the loops. I try resizing with     'picture_original[i]' and similarly with 'imwrite'.

Comment: `picture_original = cv2.imread(picture, 1)` -- That's assigning to the variable, not appending to a list.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I give a try with appending to the list.

Comment: Well, this does not worked. 'picture_original.append(cv2.imread(picture, 1))' did not append anyithing to the list. Maybe the solution will be something else.

Comment: Start simple: make it work for single input file, then separate code into a function, then you may provide a list one item a time to that function.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example to resize by a ratio and saves your image

```
    def ResizeImage(filepath, newfileName,ratio):
        image = cv2.imread(filepath)         #Open image
        height, width = image.shape[:2]      #Shapes
        image2 = cv2.resize(image, (width/ratio, height/ratio), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
        cv2.imwrite(newfileName,image2)         #saves, True if OK
        return filepath
```

So if you call

```
image = "originalpath"
resized = ResizeImage(image,"Resized_"+image,2)
newImage = cv2.imread(resized)
cv2.imshow("new",newImage)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

You should get your Image resized by half

Comment: Your answer is partially correct but does not yet serve as an example for others if they try to run your code "as is". Please read question OP asks again in combination with the comments and modify your answer accordingly up to a full working answer. Only then you get my up-vote. End of review.